# Is it possible to get the new information of another request from curl_getinfo() using the same handle?

Tags: php, curl

In the manual it says about `curl_getinfo()`:

> Information gathered by this function is kept if the handle is re-used. This means that unless a statistic is overridden internally by this function, the previous info is returned.

Does this mean that practically I can not use this function for other requests after the first request was done? Or is it possible to get the new information of another request using the same handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can reuse `curl_getinfo()` with the same handle.

Unless you execute again `curl_exec($ch)` the returned result from `curl_getinfo()` will be the same as after the first execution of `curl_exec($ch)`.

This is the intuitive behavior I think.
Also this is what the manual is trying to explain.

If you include some example code I will be able to help you more.

Comment: I thought that this is intuitive, too. But if this is the logical behavior, this notice is more or less useless. Thank you!